# WP_Query offset is returning post from prevois loop

Tags: wp-query, ajax, offsets, post-duplication

On archive pages, I let WordPress handle the archive page and load the first 10 posts, then I load more posts with AJAX requests, and this AJAX request is returning weird results.

My query inside the AJAX handler looks like this:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), // 10 by default
    'offset' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), // 10 by default
    'cat' => 8 // the category ID
);
$wp_query_archive = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

**The problem**: If the post count of the AJAX query is less than 10, i get one duplicate post.

If the posts were numbered, the first query (the default archive query that returns the first 10 posts in selected category) returns: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`, the second query made by AJAX request and described above returns: `10,11`. Which then results in post duplication on front end.

However, if there is 10 or more post for the AJAX query, the query returns: `11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20`

If there is only one post returned by the AJAX query, the query returns only that one post: `11`, which is right, but when there are two posts to return, the query returns: `10,11,12`.

When there's 5 posts for the AJAX query, the query returns the right posts too, meaning: `11,12,13,14,15`

Is there some magic to `WP_Query()` that makes it behave this way?

**Addition:** I can't use `paged` query parameter, as Jacob Peattie pointed out, because I am using that query to load posts from multiple "pages" when the user hits page with **hash** containing string "#page3" for example.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use offset, just use `'paged' => 2`, and don't bother with `posts_per_page`, since you're using the default anyway.

Comment: If the offset starts at 0, how is it then that the query returns the right posts when there is more then 10 posts to load? I am using the same query every time. And as I said, if there is 1 post to load, it returns only that post `11`, but if there are 2 posts to load, the query returns `10,11,12`.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it. After all it was really dumb error on my part.
The `WP_Query()` does not filter out unpublished posts by default. The internal archive page query does filter these posts out.

I had to add `'post_status' => 'publish'` to the `$query_args` array and everything is now working as expected.

The final query then looks like this:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), // 10 by default
    'offset' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), // 10 by default
    'cat' => 8 // the category ID
);
```

Comment: Your final query example doesn't have the bit you said you added...

Comment: I am quite distrait right now, thanks for noticing, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `paged` parameter to get the 2nd (or 3rd or 4th etc.) page:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged'     => 2,
    'cat'       => 8
);
$wp_query_archive = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

If you keep track of which page you're up to in JS then you can just pass that page number directly into `paged` to get the right posts.

PS: You were missing a `>` for the `cat` argument, and if you're getting the category by ID you should use an integer. I've corrected both of these in my example.

EDIT: If you need to handle multiple pages at once on initial load, based on the URL hash, then handle that with a different parameter in AJAX:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat'       => 8
);

if ( isset( $_GET['pages'] ) ) {
    $query_args['posts_per_page'] = $_GET['pages'] * get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
} else if ( isset( $GET['page'] ) ) {
    $query_args['paged'] = $_GET['page'];
}

$wp_query_archive = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Then in your JS, if you want multiple pages at once send `pages` with the number of pages worth of posts that you want, but when loading more send `page` with the specific page number you are after.

Comment: I can't use that because I am also loading posts on load page if the page **hash** contains string "#pageX" where **X** is the page number, and in the ajax request I then set the posts per page to `page * posts_per_page` and send that to the AJAX query. Thanks for the warning, I've fixed my question.

Comment: I don't see the problem. You can still do that for the initial query. Have your AJAX callback handle the initial load with `posts_per_page`, then additional loads just query the default posts per page with the `paged` parameter.

Comment: I've fixed it. Boy was it dumb error. Apparently, `WP_Query()` does not filter out unpublished posts. SO I was getting one unpublished post in the AJAX query, but the internal archive page query filtered it out. Thank for your help anyway!